# My Trello cards are not visible in Google Chrome, but are visible in IE

Tags: google-chrome, trello

Our team uses Trello. Other users are able to see the cards in the various lists. On any board I view, any list, almost always the cards are not visible in Google Chrome (latest/64bit). They are always visible and consistent with other uses views when using IE. Other users use Chrome without a problem.

I have tried removing/disabling a number of less popular extensions - but nothing has changed.

I login to Trello using Google accounts authentication.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I see the same problem with chrome unstable on linux (`48.0.2560.0 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)`), but it works with `46.0.2490.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and found it was related to the Plus for Trello extension.  I had inadvertently clicked the "Less" button on the Plus for Trello header.  Clicking this will hide old cards.

To correct this, click the green "More" button (near the week\year label on the top of the page).